# Issue with Java and command line error

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd, println, .class-file

I'm new to programming and need help.  Basically, I'm working exercises out of my class text book. I'm trying to execute a simple print line command. Here is the java file through NetBeans:

```
package test; 

public class Test { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
System.out.println("Test"); 
}
```

When I run it through NetBeans it is successful. However, when I try and execute through command prompt I get an error. I'm able to compile the `Test.java` file and see that it create Test.class. When I type java Test it says the following error:

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

I think I might be having problems due to the package.  Again, I'm really new to this. I know I'm probably doing something wrong that might be simple to fix.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the package name also when you run your class from command line.

```
java test.Test
```

You need to run it from one dir level up from test dir in your class path

Answer (score 0):

First of all as your class contain the package statement as the first line and you want to run the class through command line so.

1. You need to create a directory by the name of `test` save your class inside it.
2. Suppose your directory exists in some drive example `G:/test`, you need to open the terminal browse to G:/ and and compile the program as

   `javac test/Test.java`

and you can execute the program as

```
java test.Test
```